# Swift segue identifier always nil, Storyboard ID not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

I'm trying to use a Storyboard ID to tell what View I'm segue to, and based on that, pass on certain information. But no matter what I do, the `segue.identifier` is always `nil`. Heres a screenshot of my settings for the view I'm segueing to:

[image]

Comment: that's setting your storyboard id not segue identifier. Segues are set in the line that connects 2 view controllers. Click on the line and inspect the settings panel as per your screenshot above and you should be able to figure out.

Comment: In case @Rog's comment is not clear enough, you are setting the View Controller's Storyboard id, which is not the same as the Segue Identifier.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Select the segue on the storyboard, and this is the segue identifier.
 [image]